# How to generate Public and private keys for encryption using ATECC608A in C

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption, i2c, encryption-asymmetric, data-security

I am implementing encryption and decryption of data using the ATECC608A chip. I need to know how to generate public and private keys using C programming. I am working on Keil. Are there any drivers available for this? I need to implement it using I2C interfacing.

Thank you

Comment: First select an algorithm and then select a crypto library to use or copy.

Comment: After reading about different algorithms I found out that ECC is the best and safest algorithm for encryption. So can I please know how to write code for it.

Comment: Don't you think that this is a bit broad? Please study other implementations.